# Global variable from configuration file to another class

Tags: php, oop, global-variables

Simple question. I'm still new to OOP and basically learning fundamentals. I have a config.php file which is written bellow.

```
<?php
    $hName          =   'localhost';    //  Hostname :]

    $dbName         =   'db';   //  Database
    $tbAdmin        =   'admin';        //  Table administrator
    $tbPosts        =   'posts';        //  Table posts

    $dbUser         =   'phpadmin';         //  Database login uname
    $dbPass         =   'phpadmin';         //  Database login pw
?>
```

This is my functions.php file:

```
class databaseEstablish {
    public $dbc;

/**
 * Connect to database (make a connection)
 * @return boolean Return true for connected / false for not connected
 */
public function connect() {
        require_once 'config.php';

        $this->host     = $hName;
        $this->username = $dbUser;
        $this->password = $dbPass;
        $this->database = $dbname;

        $this->dbc = @mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
    }
```

Although this should probably have to work, the error message appears with the output (dots replace path, and three other dots replace line which are bellow 'require config.php':

```
Notice: Undefined variable: hName in ... ...

Notice: Undefined variable: dbUser in ... ...

Notice: Undefined variable: dbPass in ... ...

Notice: Undefined variable: dbname in ... ...
```

---

Do I have to use class and public function or constructor for config file, if not, what is the problem? As far as I know these are globabl variables in configuration file and should be accessible from any other file. Thanks.

Comment: Files which are include/required are treated as if their contents were literally part of the file at the point the require/include was executed. There is no apparently reason why most of your vars SHOULDN'T be available as written, except you do have `$dbName` in the included file, and `$dbname` in the class - PHP variables are case sensitive.  Of course, if you have `require_once` that file already elsewhere, it WON'T be required at that point. Try just `require` or `include` instead.

Answer (score 1):

create config.php file

```
define("hName", 'localhost');    //  Hostname :]
define("dbName", 'db');
define("tbPosts", 'posts');
define("dbUser", 'phpadmin');
define("dbPass", 'phpadmin');
```

create class.php

```
     require_once 'path_to/config.php';
class databaseEstablish {
    public $dbc;

/**
 * Connect to database (make a connection)
 * @return boolean Return true for connected / false for not connected
 */
public function connect() {




        $this->dbc = @mysqli_connect(hName, dbUser, dbPass, dbname);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add a `require_once` it is going to be rendered like this..

```
public function connect() {
        $hName          =   'localhost';    //  Hostname :]
        $dbName         =   'db';   //  Database
        $tbAdmin        =   'admin';        //  Table administrator
        $tbPosts        =   'posts';        //  Table posts

        $dbUser         =   'phpadmin';         //  Database login uname
        $dbPass         =   'phpadmin'; 

        $this->host     = $hName;
        $this->username = $dbUser;
        $this->password = $dbPass;
        $this->database = $dbname;
```

which is wrong *actually*.... Instead add the `require_once` outside of the class and pass the arguments to the function..

#### The modified code...

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';
class databaseEstablish {
    public $dbc;

    /**
     * Connect to database (make a connection)
     * @return boolean Return true for connected / false for not connected
     */
    public function connect($hName,$dbUser,$dbPass,$dbname) {
        

        $this->host     = $hName;
        $this->username = $dbUser;
        $this->password = $dbPass;
        $this->database = $dbname;

        $this->dbc = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
    } 
}

$dbEst = new databaseEstablish($hName,$dbUser,$dbPass,$dbname);
```

Answer (score 0):

And your require once should be like this:

```
require_once('config.php');
```

And its better to define your config as constant. Example:

```
define('hName','localhost');
define('dbUser', 'username');
```

and use it like this:

```
@mysqli_connect(hName,dbUser...
```

and so on. And I suggest don't put `@` in front of anything. 
It will suppress any error produced when calling that method. Since you are new you shouldn't ignore the error reports. The error reports are very important to troubleshoot your code.